# GhostScript removes image when ColorConversionStrategy is set to sRGB

Tags: ghostscript

we have a lot of print ready PDFs that we want to downsample to a smaller size that are suitable for online downloads. I am using Ghostscript like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs8.64\bin\gswin32c.exe" ^
 -q ^
 -dNOPAUSE ^
 -dBATCH ^
 -dSAFER ^
 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen ^
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
 -sOutputFile="c:\gs_out.pdf" 
 -f "c:\6916_DE.pdf"
```

The problem is that Ghostscript is failing to convert one image so when I am opening the resulting PDF Adobe Reader warns me about a possible error in the file. If i change the PDFSETTINGS parameter to `/print` the output works but the filesize is not reduced.

I have read the help file for `ps2pdf` and I have found one critical parameter, `ColorConversionStrategy`. When `ColorConversionStrategy` is set to `sRGB` the image will be removed, when set to `UseDeviceIndependentColor`, which is the default for the `/print` setting, the image is still there but the file size is not reduced.

The image is transparent so that might be one factor as well.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**First**, I would suggest you update your Ghostscript to the latest version, which is [v8.71](http://www.ghostscript.com/releases/). A lot of problems regarding PDF processing have been fixed since 8.64 (which you seem to use).

**Second**, if you use `-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen` on your commandline, this will implicitly also set:
 `-dColorConversionStrategy=/sRGB` and
 `-dColorImageResolution=72`.
But `-dPDFSETTINGS=/printer` implicitely uses:
 `-dColorConversionStrategy=/UseDeviceIndependentColor` as well as
 `-dColorImageResolution=300`.

If your main goal is to reduce the image size, try this:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
   -o c:\gs_out.pdf ^
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
   -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen ^
   -c ".setpdfwrite" ^
   -c "<</ColorConversionStrategy /LeaveColorUnchanged>> setdistillerparams" ^
   -c "<</ColorImageDownsampleType /Bicubic>> setdistillerparams" ^
   -f "c:\6916_DE.pdf"
```

You continue to use `/screen` (and therefor you imply `-dColorImageResolution=72`).

However the two `-c` parameters will override two other implied `/screen` settings. This could possibly overcome your problem.